# why I can use the sources or jar downloaded in my project?

Tags: java, maven, jdeveloper

I am trying to use Maven and JDeveloper for a week now and I'm always get stuck with the same problem. I can download and install the extensions and create new Maven projects. When I package or compile them I can see that the sources are being downloaded and added to my local repository but they are not added in my .jar and I cannot use them in my project unless I add them as lib manually in my project.

If I try to add the folder (where the downloaded jars are) as lib folder to project they are only added as jar and I cannot use them.

Is there another way to update my dependencies from JDeveloper? How can I integrate them properly to my project so I can use them? Is there a newer Hands-On maybe solving my problems? What am I doing wrong? Is there a template project to download maybe? I hope I could explain my problem good enough...

Comment: "However make sure that you check the ‘Deployed by Default’ checkbox or else the library will not be included on the classpath and the application will fail with a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException."

http://technology.amis.nl/2010/08/26/manage-jdeveloper-external-libraries/

Comment: or http://tompeez.wordpress.com/2011/06/01/creating-a-jar-file-in-jdeveloper/

Comment: How do the dependencies look like in the POM?

Comment: Thank you very much to all, I still can not fix it at that, look this is the pom: http://pastebin.com/NS3FpbzP

Comment: Looks fine, no scope set, so `compile` is used as default. This will propagate the dependency. I don't know JDeveloper, sorry, but does it work when you build from the command line (e.g. `mvn package`)? I don't know how JDeveloper integrates Maven, different IDEs have different approaches (looking at you, Eclipse).

Comment: i already solved this , i just had to use one plugin of maven(dependency:copy:dependencies), with this plugin i can copy all the dependencies that are declared in the pom to some specific location in the project and with this i just indicate in jdeveloper where the libraries are.